# Qual è il significato di "latte da petrolio"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Nel buio la casa l’aveva trovata a tentoni, ma la conosceva a memoria. Era bassa e sbilenca come se si fosse ricevuta sul tetto una tremenda manata e non si fosse mai
>   piú riassestata. Era grigia del medesimo grigio del tufo
>   del vallone, con finestrelle slabbrate e quasi tutte ma-
>   scherate da assiti fradici per le intemperie, con un ballatoio di legno anch’esso marcio e rattoppato con parti di
>   **latte da petrolio**.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "latte da petrolio". Non l'ho trovata nei dizionari che ho consultato, ma una ricerca su Google conferma che appare anche in altri testi. Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Latte* è il plurale di *Latta*. La latta è una lamiera di acciaio e, in questo caso, indica un contenitore fatto con questo tipo di materiale. Il suo diminutivo *lattina* indica i contenitori cilindrici per le bevande gassate. Le latte sono più grandi e possono contenere olio oppure petrolio (o benzina).

Comment: Mmmm... Non avevo pensato che fosse una parola al plurale!

Comment: Forse perché è una parola non molto usata, mentre "latte" al singolare è più frequente...

Comment: "Barili" è più usato, in effetti.

Comment: Già, @FedericoPoloni, ma parlando di petrolio il barile è un'[unità di misura](http://treccani.it/enciclopedia/barile_res-42976873-1d58-11de-bb24-0016357eee51/), mentre qui si parla di oggetti fisici.